# what does std::string str(size, '\0'); mean in c++?

Tags: c++

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
 
int main()
{
    // read() is often used for binary I/O
    std::string bin = {'\x12', '\x12', '\x12', '\x12'};
    std::istringstream raw(bin);
    std::uint32_t n;
    if(raw.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&n), sizeof n))
        std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase << n << '\n';
 
    // prepare file for next snippet
    std::ofstream("test.txt", std::ios::binary) << "abcd1\nabcd2\nabcd3";
 
    // read entire file into string
    if(std::ifstream is{"test.txt", std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate}) {
        auto size = is.tellg();
        std::string str(size, '\0'); // construct string to stream size
        is.seekg(0);
        if(is.read(&str[0], size))
            std::cout << str << '\n';
    }
}
```

for example:
I can read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg to get what does `tellg` do. so I also understand `ate` and `seekg`
but I don't understand `std::string str(size, '\0'); // construct string to stream size`
even i read: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: See constructor number 2 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

Comment: It constructs a `std::string` with `size` NUL characters. BTW `std::string` can contain NUL characters inside the (length of the) string. This is not possible with NUL-terminated strings.

Comment: After `is.read()` (which reads into the beginning of `str`), `str` is not set to the correct length. I would guess that `cout` would output NUL characters after the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

Just a string of '\0' with the length is 'size'.
std::string is not C-Style string, it could contain any data.

See this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void print_the_content(size_t size) {
  std::string str(size, '\0'); // construct string to stream size

  for (auto it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << static_cast<uint32_t>(*it) << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

#define TEST_CNT 5
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  for (auto i = 0; i < TEST_CNT; ++i) {
    std::cout << std::endl << "Now test counter: " << i << std::endl;
    print_the_content(i);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

```sh
g++ test.cpp
./a.out
```

The output:

```sh
Now test counter: 0


Now test counter: 1
0

Now test counter: 2
0 0

Now test counter: 3
0 0 0

Now test counter: 4
0 0 0 0
```

Comment: std::string str(0, '\0'); is equivalent to std::string str; and initialize an empty string, right ?

Comment: @kingsjester yes

Comment: @ZongruZhan According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string the default constructor constructs an empty string.

Answer (score -2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string

NUL-terminated string is stored in an array, and the string itself consists of all the characters in an array prior to the first '\0' character (called a NUL in ASCII)
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ascii-nul-ascii-0-0-and-numeric-literal-0

> Here we will see the ASCII NUL, ASCII 0 and the Numeric Literal 0. The
> ASCII null is represented as 0x00, and zero is represented as 0x30.
> The ASCII NUL character is used to denote the end of the string in C
> or C++.

for example:

```
 string a1= {'H','e','l','l','o','\0','i','d','1','0','t'};
        cout<<a1;
```

will return `Hello id10t`.
So

```
string a(5,'\0');
    cout<<a.size()<<endl;
```

will construct a string with 5 characters, ended by null-terminated string.
based on

> Constructs the string with count copies of character ch. This
> constructor is not used for class template argument deduction if the
> Allocator type that would be deduced does not qualify as an allocator
> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

update.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string
base on example code:

```
  {
    // before C++11, overload resolution selects string(InputIt first, InputIt last)
    // [with InputIt = int] which behaves *as if* string(size_type count, charT ch)
    // after C++11 the InputIt constructor is disabled for integral types and calls:
    std::cout << "β) string(size_type count, charT ch) is called: ";
    std::string s(3, std::toupper('a'));
    std::cout << quoted(s) << '\n'; // "AAA"
  }
```

It construct `size` size of string.

Comment: 'ended by null-terminated string' - it only contains NUL elements ...